# How create solid rainbow border with CSS?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients, repeating-linear-gradient

How to create the following rainbow effect using CSS?

i.e. top rounded border with solid rainbow color stops (without inserting html).

[image]

Colors are: `#c4e17f. #f7fdca, #fad071, #f0766b, #db9dbe, #c49cdf, #6599e2, #61c2e4`.

**What I have tried so far:**

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #c4e17f 50px, #f7fdca 50px, #fad071 50px, #f0766b, #db9dbe, #c49cdf, #6599e2, #61c2e4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose you don’t want to just create a picture of that and set it as the background?

Comment: By picture if you mean a graphic, NO. But if you mean CSS background-image via some gradient or so, YES.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not that far off. Just need to set the color stops with equal values so they act as solid colors, and the background size to have it only on top.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
  #c4e17f 0px, #c4e17f 50px,
  #f7fdca 50px, #f7fdca 100px,
  #fad071 100px, #fad071 150px,
  #f0766b 150px, #f0766b 200px,
  #db9dbe 200px, #db9dbe 250px,
  #c49cdf 250px, #c49cdf 300px,
  #6599e2 300px, #6599e2 350px,
  #61c2e4 350px, #61c2e4 400px);
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the browser support for this is pretty good: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients

Answer (score 4):

You could use `after` pseudo-element with `linear-gradient` to create border.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-round-rainbow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(196,225,127,1) 0%, rgba(196,225,127,1) 12%, rgba(247,253,202,1) 12%, rgba(247,253,202,1) 25%, rgba(250,208,113,1) 25%, rgba(250,208,113,1) 39%, rgba(240,118,107,1) 39%, rgba(240,118,107,1) 52%, rgba(219,157,190,1) 52%, rgba(219,157,190,1) 65%, rgba(196,156,223,1) 65%, rgba(196,156,223,1) 78%, rgba(101,153,226,1) 78%, rgba(101,153,226,1) 89%, rgba(97,194,228,1) 89%, rgba(97,194,228,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice approach :)

Answer (score 3):

The solutions already provided are perfect but I will add another one using **border** and gradient. You can also use your gradient as a border-image but pay attention as this won't work with border-radius.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius:5px;
  border-top: 10px solid;
  border-image:linear-gradient(90deg,
  #c4e17f 0 50px,
  #f7fdca 0 100px,
  #fad071 0 150px,
  #f0766b 0 200px,
  #db9dbe 0 250px,
  #c49cdf 0 300px,
  #6599e2 0 350px,
  #61c2e4 0 400px) 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, your addition is still helpful. And for you know, my first intuition was too to use gradient with border.

Comment: @abdul-wahab i was pretty sure about this when i saw your code ;) that's why i added this ... as it can be a bit difficult to handle the linear-gradient as background and adjust size to make it like border but it remain a great solution, simply pay attention to padding as background is a part of the content unlike border

Answer (score 2):

This problem does not necessarily require pseudo-elements or additional layers.

To achieve a stopped gradient, declare colors at intersections.

To limit background-image height to 10px (or any arbitrary number), but retain 100% width, use `background-size: 10px 100%`.

To prevent the gradient from repeating use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #c4e17f 0%, #c4e17f 12.5%, #f7fdca 12.5%, #f7fdca 25%, #fad071 25%, #fad071 37.5%, #f0766b 37.5%, #f0766b 50%, #db9dbe 50%, #db9dbe 62.5%, #c49cdf 62.5%, #c49cdf 75%, #6599e2 75%, #6599e2 87.5%, #61c2e4 87.5%, #61c2e4 100%), white;
  background-size: 100% 10px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, just for the giggles. This time with multiple box shadows.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow:
/*white overlay*/
  0 -150px 0 -10px white inset,
/*"borders" that cover each other*/
  50px 0 0 0 #c4e17f inset,
  100px 0 0 0 #f7fdca inset,
  150px 0 0 0 #fad071 inset,
  200px 0 0 0 #f0766b inset,
  250px 0 0 0 #db9dbe inset,
  300px 0 0 0 #c49cdf inset,
  350px 0 0 0 #6599e2 inset,
  400px 0 0 0 #61c2e4 inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Not really practical, as we need to know the height of the div. But they make for some cool effects with border-radius :p

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow:
/*white overlay*/
  0 -150px 0 -10px white inset,
/*"borders" that cover each other*/
  50px 0 0 0 #c4e17f inset,
  100px 0 0 0 #f7fdca inset,
  150px 0 0 0 #fad071 inset,
  200px 0 0 0 #f0766b inset,
  250px 0 0 0 #db9dbe inset,
  300px 0 0 0 #c49cdf inset,
  350px 0 0 0 #6599e2 inset,
  400px 0 0 0 #61c2e4 inset;
  
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

and last but not least, one with rounded borders + rounded box-shadow, which makes for an awesome look imho. And makes a little more sense.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-top:10px;
}
  
.top-round-rainbow::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
  height:10px; width:100%;
  box-shadow:
  50px 0 0 0 #c4e17f inset,
  100px 0 0 0 #f7fdca inset,
  150px 0 0 0 #fad071 inset,
  200px 0 0 0 #f0766b inset,
  250px 0 0 0 #db9dbe inset,
  300px 0 0 0 #c49cdf inset,
  350px 0 0 0 #6599e2 inset,
  400px 0 0 0 #61c2e4 inset;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new layer, this with let you specify the size of the white area.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.container {
  background: #596678;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-round-rainbow {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-width: 4px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #c4e17f 50px, #f7fdca 50px, #fad071 50px, #f0766b, #db9dbe, #c49cdf, #6599e2, #61c2e4);
}

.white-layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: white;
  border-radius:  0 0 4px 4px;
  border-top-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-round-rainbow">
    <div class="white-layer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you examine more and see if gradient can be made with solid stops, as in the image. Then we'll see how to avoid adding an additional element.